# How to hide header and footer in tizen webviewer sample app?

Tags: c++, tizen, bada, tizen-native-app

I am building a native c/c++ app of tizen which will only open my website in the webviewer.
I am using webviewer sample app for this. I am not able to hide the header and footer which comes with this sample app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done,doing this - 
  r = __pMainForm->Construct(FORM_STYLE_NORMAL | FORM_STYLE_PORTRAIT_INDICATOR | FORM_STYLE_LANDSCAPE_INDICATOR_AUTO_HIDE | (!FORM_STYLE_HEADER) | (!FORM_STYLE_FOOTER)); 
and removing all the dependent code on Header and Footer did the work.